# Apple Mach-O Linker Error - linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, linker-errors

I have this error in my xcode. I have done everything which is said in other questions same as this ,  i have checked my .m and .mm i have removed any file similar to each other and still not working.

It's making me crazy please help me.

I have added an asset to my game in unity ( IOS native ) and after that this error appear when i want to test on my phone. It is 2 days that i'm searching for a solution to work.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Volumes/PHOENIX/flight Drift - test  21/LibrariesPlugins/iOS'

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Volumes/PHOENIX/flight Drift - test  21/FrameworksPlugins/iOS'

ld: library not found for -lOneSignal

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have updated the screenshots

Comment: Check the Header search path in build setting tab

Comment: @Pouya Etemadi Hi. 1) Fast way - Just rename the directory `flight Drift - test 21` to the `flight_Drift_test_21`. 2) Long way - read how to escape a spaces in the folder paths.

Comment: @Pouya Etemadi  Can you please add screenshots for you 'Framework Search Paths', 'Header Search Paths' and 'Library Search Paths'. as this error is probably because your path to this library is not correct

Comment: @Anas iqbal  , i have added the screenshots of the error and libraries

Comment: @Mozilla it shouldn't be from the space between the words because i have installed the other version of this game before with the same name (different numbers only ) . this happened after i added IOS Native asset to my game in unity .

Comment: @PouyaEtemadi Hi. Can you show where the "OneSignalLib.a"-file is placed?

Comment: @mozilla i have added anouther screenshot which shows the search for OneSignal files .

Comment: @mozilla i checked my Compile sources and OneSignal.h wasn't there , i added it , cleaned and rebuilt but still the error exists

Comment: @PouyaEtemadi Is a "OneSignal" external lib with headers (e.g. a pod lib)? Or it a sources only? The linker wants get the file "libOneSignal.a", but can't found it.

Comment: @mozilla "OneSignal" is a file in the asset which i used in my game project  . it has "OneSignal.h" "libOneSignal.a" and some other more . i have added it in compile sources it didn't work , i added it in link binary in frameworks also it didn't work . it's making me crazy :(

Comment: @PouyaEtemadi Set the 'recursive' for the 'Library Search Path' and ensure what the file 'libOneSignal.a' is placed in the set folder.

Comment: @mozilla , yeesssss finally after 3 days this annoying error is gone , thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the images you have uploaded:

1. remove inverted commas ("") around $(SRCROOT)/Libraries in 'Library Search Paths'
2. remove inverted commas around $(SRCROOT)/UnityAds in 'Header Search Paths'
3. Cannot say anything about 'Framework Search Paths' you have uploaded any image for that. (Or probably you uploaded the wrong image by mistake).

Is there a space between your "Libraries Plugins" and "Frameworks Plugins" folders? if yes then the paths inside you 'Library Search Paths' and 'Framework Search Paths' are not are not having that space.

Replace:

```
$(SRCROOT)/Libraries\Plugins/iOS
```

with

```
$(SRCROOT)/Libraries\ Plugins/iOS
```

in your 'Library Search Paths' (just added a space after '\')

AND Replace:

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)/Frameworks\Plugins/iOS
```

with

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)/Frameworks\ Plugins/iOS
```

in your 'Framework Search Paths' (just added a space after '\')

Comment: i have updated the screenshots and i also changed what you said but still i have that error :( .